# Как сделать двойной .decode()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = "Привет\n\n".encode()
a = str(a)
a = a.encode()
print(a)


b"b'\\xd0\\x9f\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xb2\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x82\\n\\n'"
```

То есть внутри bytes есть ещё bytes но в строчном виде а питон не позволяет мне сделать двойной .decode().
Как я могу это сделать?
Это пример, просто нужно найти решение как это сделать.

Comment: По-хорошему, разобраться почему два раза в байты закодировалось. А так - decode, потом literal_eval и еще рез decode

Comment: Ну, не нужно a = str(a) делать после encode, потом еще раз энкодить, тогда и декодить два раза не нужно будет

Comment: Дело не в этом, я знаю что так не нужно делать, это пример. Я через библиотеку сокет получаю такие данные, а сконвертировать в utf-8 2 раза не могу

Comment: Ну значит через библиотеку сокет не нужно отправлять так данные, тогда и приходить нормально будет. Лучше устранить причину проблемы, а не костыли городить вокруг нее.

Comment: Ну так то да, но сталкиваюсь с одной проблемой, 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 4: invalid start byte, это на стороне клиента

Comment: Если в строку не перегонять, то нормально декодироваться должно. Если кодировать и декодировать одной и той же кодировкой конечно.

Comment: кстати, я попробовал на стороне сервера decode потом literal_eval и ещё раз decode, ошибка выходит:  'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 4: invalid start byte, попробовал utf-16 но буквы меняются на иероглифы

Comment: Должно быть условно `x = "Привет!\n"; socket.send(x.encode('utf-8'))`, на принимающей стороне - `socket.recv().decode('utf-8')`, и никаких проблем с кодировками не будет.

Comment: P.S. по крайней мере не будет, если данные приняты с начала, а не с середины символа, например.